# PHP and EXIF data for Google Maps mashup

Tags: php, arrays, google-maps, foreach

I am trying to create a google maps mashup that will show the location of each image I take with my mobile. I am having some trouble with it and have been unable to find anything on google to help me out.

Basically I have a script that will find all images in a folder and put those image names into an array - this is that script:

```
<?php
// create a handler for the directory
$handler = opendir("images");

// open directory and walk through the filenames
while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
// if file isn't this directory or its parent, add it to the results
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
$results[] = $file;
    }
}

// tidy up: close the handler
closedir($handler);

// done!
print_r ($results);     
?>
```

This gives me the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => IMAG0005.jpg
    [1] => IMAG0030.jpg
)
```

This part is fine and works as expected. Now I use this array to get the EXIF data that I need from each image. The problem is that if I use an array for the output I get two separate arrays and am unable to do anything with them to create new markers on the map. I use the following code to get the EXIF data

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($results); ++$i) {
//print $results[$i];

$arrPhotoExif = exif_read_data('images/'.$results[$i]);

$intLatDeg = GpsDivide($arrPhotoExif["GPSLatitude"][0]);
$intLatMin = GpsDivide($arrPhotoExif["GPSLatitude"][1]);
$intLatSec = GpsDivide($arrPhotoExif["GPSLatitude"][2]);

$intLongDeg = GpsDivide($arrPhotoExif["GPSLongitude"][0]);
$intLongMin = GpsDivide($arrPhotoExif["GPSLongitude"][1]);
$intLongSec = GpsDivide($arrPhotoExif["GPSLongitude"][2]);

// round to 5 = approximately 1 meter accuracy
$intLatitude = round(DegToDec($arrPhotoExif["GPSLatitudeRef"],
$intLatDeg,$intLatMin,$intLatSec),5);

$intLongitude = round(DegToDec($arrPhotoExif["GPSLongitudeRef"],
$intLongDeg,$intLongMin,$intLongSec), 5);

$markers = array("$intLatitude, $intLongitude");
print_r($markers);
```

That last piece of code prints this as the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 51.508742, -0.134583
)
Array
(
    [0] => 38.410558, 17.314453
)
```

I am unable to use this to list the markers - according to google docs the code must look like the following to create new markers on the map.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: **THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO OUTPUT THE GPS CO-ORDS**, 
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

If I try to loop through the markers array I only get one result, obviously as it is creating two arrays with only one piece of data in each.

Can some please help point in the right direction? I want to learn and don't expect to be spoonfed, if someone could just help me get the ball rolling I can pick up from there.

Thank you, I know it's a bit of a long post.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect you want to build a single array with multiple entries. Instead of:

```
$markers = array("$intLatitude, $intLongitude");
```

...try using:

```
$markers[] = array("$intLatitude, $intLongitude");
```

That will add the new latitude and longitude string as a new element in the array, rather than overwriting the array each time.

Following the loop, $markers should then contain:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51.508742, -0.134583
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 38.410558, 17.314453
        )

)
```

Which you can then loop through and process as necessary.

Comment: Hi. I followed your advice and it does indeed do as you stated, but I am also getting extra data with it. This is what your suggestion prints out -    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51.49786, -3.17668
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51.49786, -3.17668
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51.46312, -3.16553
        )

)

Comment: sorry, i had left the print_r inside the loop, moving it outside the loop has now given me the data in the format you stated. I will now try and get through the data and output it correctly. thank you